# Would it be possible to change from titanium Certified App Developer Account to Indie account?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

Excuse me, may I ask you a question?

The question because there was no response from support.

Have a titanium Certified App Developer Account.
If you have a titanium Certified App Developer Account
Would it be possible to change Indie account to free of charge?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Since this is not a technical question or a question related to code, this is not a stackoverflow question, but really, an Appcelerator question which should go to support.

Comment: I'm sorry. 
I will be careful from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only if your account was created before June 1st 2014